# How to easily copy a SQL Server database without using restore or attach?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I would to copy a SQL Server 2012 database from one server to another with the least amount of manual work and without doing a restore or attach database because I don't have access to the source server or backup files.

I would like to have a copy of all the objects and data. This includes tables with primary (including identity designation) and foreign keys, views, stored procedures, constraints and triggers.

If I use SSMS, I have to use a combination of data imports and scripting the objects. One issue with this is that I have many tables and manually enabling identity inserts is a hassle. Maybe one way is to use a diff tool to do all this work for me if possible or find a way to script the identity properties across the tables.

Is there a simpler more straightforward way to copy a database?

Comment: **Tasks** >> **Generate Scripts..**

Comment: @ahmed  I already mentioned it.

Comment: You could use Red Gate SQL Compare.

Comment: You could try using the diff tools in SSDT though its a bit of messing about to activate them. The fact is backup/restore is the easiest. Do you mean to say you can't get to the backup file? Can you use xp_cmdshell to copy it somewhere you can get to it? I don't quite understand the constraints you are under - are you saying you can't get to the local drives to pickup a backup?

Comment: What about **tablediff.exe** utility ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/tablediff-utility

Comment: @Nick Yes I don't have access to the local drives of those servers. I don't have permission to execute xp_cmdshell.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich, what permissions do you **have** on the server? Can you run `BACKUP` statement? You can tell it to write backup to some remote disk that is a shared network resource, not on a local disk. Or you can run only `SELECT`?

Comment: You can try to use OPENROWSET then select into to copy the data from server to local pc. Sorry for my suggestion.

Comment: But i doubt to Stored  Proc, views, Primary key etc. even triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Replication. There are different types. Transactional will keep your copy updated with any changes. Snapshot will not, etc.

Without access to the server, I am not sure what you can do at all?

Comment: Replication is overkill and is not an option. I just want a one time copy once a while. I can do stuff in SSMS like I mentioned. Not sure what you mean I can't do anything at all.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich replication can just be snapshot once in a while. Or just do snapshot. I didn't mean to say you couldn't do anything at all...I asked a question, because saying, 'I don't have access to the source server or backup files.', would raise the question. Anyway, good luck.